# `after_commit` callback on `update` doesn't trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have defined `after_commit` callback on `update`. It doesn't trigger in rspec.

Here is my callback :

```
after_commit :notify_trip, :if => Proc.new { |trip| trip.can_send_schedule_notification? }, on: :update
```

Here is my rspec code :

```
@work_order.update_attributes(:status_id => statuses(:scheduled).id, :tour_id => @tour.id)
@work_order.run_callbacks(:commit)
assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0].to).to include(@user.email)
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0].subject).to include("Your trip has been scheduled!")
```

Here callback is not calling and `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` returning `0`

Is there any suggestion on this.

Comment: if there is no commit, it won't trigger.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

```
@work_order.update_attributes(:status_id => statuses(:scheduled).id, :tour_id => @tour.id)
@work_order.instance_variable_set(:@_start_transaction_state, {})
@work_order.run_callbacks(:commit)
```

**Explanation**

I had a same similar situation with Rails 4.0.1:

```
@work_order = WorkOrder.create(status_id: 1, order_id: 2)
@work_order.update_attributes(status_id: 4, order_id: 5)
@work_order.run_callbacks(:commit)
```

when the model implementation look something like this:

```
class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :notify_trip, :if => Proc.new { |trip| trip.can_send_schedule_notification? }, on: :update
  after_commit :do_something, on: :create
end
```

and every time when I call `@work_order.run_callbacks(:commit)` then it would run the after_commit on create method - do_something. That happens because after the `@work_order` is created by (`@work_order = WorkOrder.create(status_id: 1, order_id: 2)`) a instance variable called `@_start_transaction_state` is initialized, but never cleared. `@_start_transaction_state` is used in ActiveRecord::Transaction module to track a transaction process as far as I understood from reading the code.

So before calling `run_callbacks` if we clear up `@_start_transaction_state`, then we will be able to run the `after_commit on: update` callbacks

```
@work_order.instance_variable_set(:@_start_transaction_state, {})
@work_order.run_callbacks(:commit)
```

There's one more option which is a little bit cleaner:

```
@work_order.send(:clear_transaction_record_state)
@work_order.run_callbacks(:commit)
```

I know that the solution is hacky and I'm not sure if that might introduce some side effects, especially with nested transactions, but was the only variant that worked for me in Rails 4.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit), you need to use the [test_after_commit](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) gem to have `after_commit` hooks get fired in tests. this will be no longer needed on rails 5.0+.

Another alternative could be putting following code at the end of the body of the it block:

```
subject.run_callbacks(:commit)
```

Comment: I already tried it but it is not working with on update. If I didn't mention `on update` with `after_commit` then it works perfectly.

Comment: try `after { subject.run_callbacks(:commit) }` then.